# primefaces linechart not visible

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

This is my .xhtml

```
<div id="detailed_div_graph" align="center">
            <p:lineChart id="linear" value="#{ChartBean.linearModel}" legendPosition="e" 
                title="Medical Data" minY="0" maxY="10" style="height:300px"/>
        </div>
```

This is my `ChartBean` code:

```
public class ChartBean implements Serializable {

private CartesianChartModel linearModel;

public ChartBean() {  
    createLinearModel();  
}

public CartesianChartModel getLinearModel() {  
    return linearModel;  
} 

private void createLinearModel() {  
    linearModel = new CartesianChartModel();  

    LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();  
    series1.setLabel("BP");  

    series1.set(1, 2);  
    series1.set(2, 1);  
    series1.set(3, 3);  
    series1.set(4, 6);  
    series1.set(5, 8);  

    linearModel.addSeries(series1);  
}  

}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Here you assume that this constructor will be called.

```
public ChartBean() {  
    createLinearModel();  
}
```

Jsf has phases and you should take into account them.

If you want your createLinearModel() method to be called at first just after the bean first initialized, you should annotate it with @PostConstruct annotation

```
@PostConstruct 
private void createLinearModel(){
    ...
}
```